# JS Multiple popover on same page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

The second popover html

```
<div class="extras">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2 class="heading-area">Garlic Bread</h2>
        <div class="popover-markup1"> 
            <div class="trigger form-group form-group-lg form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-users input-icon input-icon-highlight"></i>
                <input type="text" name="gralic-passanger-info" id="gralic-passanger-info" class="form-control" value="Garlic Bread">
                <input type="hidden" name="gralic-passengers" id="gralic-passengers" class="form-control" value="1" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="content1 hide" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-7"><strong>Garlic Bread</strong></label>
                    <div class="input-group number-spinner1 col-md-5">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <a class="" data-dir="dwn"><img src="assets/img/remove.png"></a>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" disabled name="adult1" id="adult1" class="form-control text-center" value="1" max=9 min=1>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <a class="" data-dir="up"><img src="assets/img/add-more.png"></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want two popover fields on the same page, But the second popover is replicating the first one values only, The Second popover does not work properly.

How to change the js for the second popover?
Please guide me.

I have referred from the following fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gvrc5drL/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gvrc5drL/1/

Comment: it is working fine in the fiddle right..? what is your issue. I'm not getting it.

Comment: @Abdul Waheed: i want to clone the field, But it does not working